# Как создать функцию в С, которая может принимать как 2 аргумента, так и 3?

Tags: c

Есть функция `bar(const char *a, struct my_struct1 b, struct my_struct2 c)`, как сделать так, чтобы эту функцию можно было вызывать от двух аргументов, то есть так: `bar(const char *a, struct my_struct1 b)`?

Comment: Что вы собираетесь делать с третьим аргументом в ней? Или каким образом внутри функции хотите определять, вызвана она с двумя или тремя аргументами? (Вообще же, для функций с разным количеством аргументов смотрите на [varargs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Третий аргумент мне нужен, чтобы можно было понять, использовать массив функции по умолчанию или использовать те, которые были переданы, но важно, что можно вызывать как с 2 параметрами, тогда по умолчанию, так и с 3, тогда использовать то, что было передано.

Comment: Вы так и не сказали, как именно надеятесь узнать внутри функции, вызвана bar с 2-мя или 3-мя аргументами

Comment: Если у вас не теоретический интерес, а практическая задача, то имеет смысл рассказать о ней подробнее, вероятно тогда вам смогут предложить подходящий алгоритм ее решения

Comment: У меня есть такая функция `int calc_evaluate(const char *buffer, calc_result *res, calc_function functions[])`, хочу поддержать возможность вызывать её так `calc_evaluate("(100)", &res)` и так `calc_evaluate("5+pow(1, 1)", &res, funcs)`, возможно ли так сделать в языке С?

Comment: Вы всегда можете написать  функцию, принимающую переменное число аргуменов -- `int calc_evaluate(const char *b, calc_result *r, ...) { ...`. Проблема в том, что по значению первых двух вам надо понять, есть ли третий. Насколько понял код из вашего комментария у вас третий аргумент это массив указателей на функции. Если он задан, то вы хотите использовать его, если нет, то что-то по умолчанию. Наверное проще всего всегда передавать третий аргумент (массив). Если надо использовать умолчания, то в качестве третьего передайте 0. Imho это самое простое и надежное решение.

Comment: В С перегрузки функций нет. Если она нужна - используйте С++.

Comment: Так как третий аргумент это указатель , то проще передавать третим аргументом NULL, это значит как вариант с двумя аргументами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать библиотеку с переменным количеством аргументов. Но в этом случае определить дали аргумент или нет можно только с помощью передачи нулевого указателя.

```
// -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic --std=c11 -Winline 
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef int calc_result ;
typedef int(*calc_function)(int) ;

int calc_evaluate(const char *buffer, calc_result *res, ... /*calc_function functions[]*/){
    va_list arguments;
    va_start ( arguments, res );
    calc_function * functions = va_arg ( arguments, calc_function * );
    if ( functions )
      /* если аргумент есть */ ;
    else 
      /* если указатель нулевой */ ;
    va_end ( arguments );
}

calc_evaluate("",&res,(calc_function*)0);
```

А если хочется два варианта : без третьего указателя или с третим нулевым, то и приходим опять к началу вопроса.

В одиннадцатом стандарте можно определить функции с одним именем но с разным **типом** аргумента.

```
int calc_evaluate(const char *buffer, calc_result *res,
  calc_function functions[]);
int calc_evaluatev(const char *buffer, calc_result *res);

#define calc_evaluate2t(X,Y,Z)          \
  _Generic(   (Z),       \
    calc_function * : calc_evaluate(X,Y,Z) , \
    int * : calc_evaluatev(X,Y) )

calc_evaluate2t("",&res,(int*)0);
calc_evaluate2t("",&res,functions);
```

Но к макросу и к `Generic` нужно предложить третий аргумент чтобы определить тип. Опять пришли к тому-же.

Есть способ передавать аргументы в функцию с помощью **одной** структуры разного типа. Но эти типы нужно объявлять и писанины будет много.

```
typedef
    struct  {
        const char *buffer;
        calc_result *res;
    }   args2 ;

typedef
    struct  {
        const char *buffer;
        calc_result *res;
        calc_function * functions ;
    }   args3 ;

int calc_evaluate2(args2);
int calc_evaluate3(args3);

#define calc_evaluatet(X)          \
    _Generic(   (X),       \
        args2: calc_evaluate2,       \
        args3: calc_evaluate3 )(X)

calc_evaluatet(((args2){"",&res}));
calc_evaluatet(((args3){"",&res,functions}));
```

Имя типа структур нужно задавать вручную и писанины опять много лишней.

Не проще ли вам сделать две функции с разным именем?

```
int calc_evaluateN(const char *buffer, calc_result *res) ;
int calc_evaluateF(const char *buffer, calc_result *res,
  calc_function functions[]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться макросом va_arg библиотеки stdarg.h.

https://learnc.info/c/vararg_functions.html

Comment: Ответ ссылка, за это минус